# Best place to declare JFrame variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am writing a program with a series of different interfaces. Each interface is stored in a seperate class extending JPanel, and to swap between interfaces I set the content pane of a JFrame to the required JPanel.

So my question is: where is the best place to declare the JFrame? Should it be in a completely seperate class? Should it be be in the class containing the first interface to be loaded? Should I create a new class extending JFrame? Is there some convention which I should be following? It seems a little excessive to pass the JFrame as an argument to each panel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I set the content pane of a JFrame"* That's the wrong approach.  Create a `JPanel`.  Give it a `CardLayout`. Add that panel to a frame (or an applet or window or dialog..) and display it. Use the card layout to switch between views.

Comment: OK thanks that does look like a better approach :), but still a similar problem remains. Is there a conventional location to declare the panel using CardLayout?

Comment: Just out of interest, why is setting a new content pane the wrong approach? Is it for performance reasons, or is a card layout just more conventional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use some approach like this...

Declaring an enum with your possible interfaces:

```
public enum PossibleInterfacesEnum {
    INTERFACE_1 {
        public javax.swing.JPanel getInstance() {
            return new javax.swing.JPanel();
        }
    },
    INTERFACE_2 {
        public javax.swing.JPanel getInstance() { 
            return new javax.swing.JPanel();
        }
    };

    public abstract javax.swing.JPanel getInstance();
}
```

Then, I would create a class that manages my frame, like this:

```
public class MyFrameManager {

    private JFrame     frame;
    private CardLayout frameLayout;

    public MyFrameManager() {
        super();
        frame = new JFrame("My App");
        frame.setLayout(frameLayout = new CardLayout());
        frame.setSize(320, 240);

        // Adding to the layout all possible interfaces, each referenced by its name
        for (PossibleInterfacesEnum e : PossibleInterfacesEnum.values()) {
            frameLayout.addLayoutComponent(e.getInstance(), e.name());
        }

    }

    public void showInterface(PossibleInterfacesEnum e) {
        frameLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), e.name());
        if (!frame.isVisible()) {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

At last, from my app, I would use my frame manager, indicating the interface I want to show:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyFrameManager f = new MyFrameManager();
                f.showInterface(PossibleInterfacesEnum.INTERFACE_1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this is usefull for you.

Regards,